# Java Set gets duplicate entry

Tags: java, collections, set, unique, hashset

JavaDoc defines set as :

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2)

To verify the same, i created a very simple program:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class CheckHashSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Employee> set = new HashSet<Employee>();
        set.add(new Employee(10));
        set.add(new Employee(10));
        System.out.println(set.size());
        System.out.println(new Employee(10).equals(new Employee(10)));
    }

    private static class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
        private final int id;
        public Employee(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Employee o) {
            return this.id - o.id; 
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(obj instanceof Employee) {
                return compareTo((Employee)obj)==0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the program is

```
2
true
```

This means `new Employee(10).equals(new Employee(10))` returns true whereas `set.add(new Employee(10)); set.add(new Employee(10));` adds the object twice.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Read: http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Employee` class doesn't override `hashCode` - it needs to do so in order for any hash-based collection to work.

For example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Did you really type that answer and format it in 21 seconds? I give up :-)

Comment: That makes things a little bit better.

Answer (score 4):

Your class voilates the joint contract on [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever `equals` method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, **which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.**

In your case, equal objects do not necessarily have equal hash codes. This is what's confusing the `HashSet`, since `Employees` with the same `id` could end up in different buckets and consequently get treated as if they weren't equal.

To fix, override `hashCode()` [for example, to simply return `this.id`].

Comment: thanks. this is the solution i was looking for.
JavaDoc mentions it as **The Set interface places additional stipulations, beyond those inherited from the Collection interface, on the contracts of all constructors and on the contracts of the add, equals and hashCode methods.**

Comment: @PC.: No, that's not the same thing at all. That's placing additional stipulation on the *collection* - the javadoc that aix quoted is about the requirements for the *elements* in a collection.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` is based on [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure so you have to override both `equals` and `hashCode` methods in class `Employee` to make it work properly.

However you can use another `Set` implementation not based on hash table such as `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here is your problem `return this.id - o.id;` rather you check `return this.equals(o)` that return true or false.

Comment: what could be wrong in this.id - o.id
i don't think this is the issue